# problem with the date under than 10 in my spring java project

Tags: java, html, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Java project. The search date sort in my page not work if I import value under than "10" like : 11/09/2018 .. I receive the alert "bad request. The pattern in my controller class is:

```java
@DateTimeFormat(pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy").
```

Can you help me please .. thanks ..

this is the date pattern code in the Java:

```java
public GeneralResponse getCouponsUpToACertainDate(@PathVariable("companyId") long companyId,
        @PathVariable("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDate date)
```

and in the HTML page:

```html
<input id="searchDate" type="date"  style="width: 160px" placeholder="Another">
```

Comment: `dd-MM-yyyy` and `11/09/2018` don't match, either the pattern has to be `dd/MM/yyyy` or the date `11-09-2018`.

Comment: but why 11/14/2018 is work ? and all the values upper than 10 .. with the same pattern date

Comment: I'm not that familiar with spring or spring boot but I'd guess that if this works then there might be some fallback.

Comment: I think that the problem with the zero .. the code not read the zero .. but i dont know what i can do .. thank you

Comment: Well, you could at least try with the change in pattern or data. I can't tell about `@DateTimeFormat` but the docs say that it follows the `SimpleDateFormat` patterns and those clearly allow and support zeros.

Comment: i have this exception : Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '5-11-2018'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [5-11-2018]

Comment: You should post exceptions in your question as they can have complete stacktraces in that case as well as better formatting.

Comment: Please refer this thread: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/86986-datetimeformat-for-pathvariable-not-converting

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said, you should first try to use the correct date format.

In your comment you mentioned the date „11/14/2018“. 
So the correct format would be 
`MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: i change the pattern but its a same problem .. i check the rest after that i run the program " Date/5-11-2020" its remove the zero .. because that its not read the pattern correctly ... we can solute the problem of the zeroin the day and in the month .